# How could I use diagonalization to find the determinant of this statement?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix A

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2\\ 
 0& 2 &0 \\ 
 2&3  & 1
\end{bmatrix}

I have found the characteristic polynomial, and it's $-\lambda ^{3}+4\lambda ^{2}-\lambda-6$ and I want to find the determinant of $(A^{3}-4A^{2}+A)^{2012}$

So what I have is

$-\lambda ^{3}+4\lambda ^{2}-\lambda-6=0$

$\lambda ^{3}-4\lambda ^{2}+\lambda=-6$

From some questions I asked around here, I found out about the  Cayley Hamilton. With which I get:

$A ^{3}-4A^{2}+A=-6I$

The first part of which is what I need for my statement.

I know that for diagonalization, I can use $(P^{-1}AP)^{k} = P^{-1}A^{k}P$ and therefor $A^{k}=PD^{k}P^{-1}$.

Can I use this statement in order to find the determinant of $(A^{3}-4A^{2}+A)^{2012}$ ?

Comment: If you know $A^3-4A^2+A=6I_3$, then you need the determinant of $(6I_3)^{2012}$.  What is $\det{(6I_3)}$?

Comment: $det(6I_{3})$ would be 216,right?

Comment: So my answer would be $216^{2012}$ ?

Comment: yes...that would be correct

Comment: As @Sami has it, it would be $(6^{2012})^3=216^{2012}$.

Comment: the answer would be $2012*216$ or $216^{2012}$? I missed something there

Comment: I mistyped it earlier...kids are throwing dry erase markers around....the latter is correct...$216^{2012}$

Comment: Just to reiterate, the determinant of a product is just the product of the determinants.  So $$\det{((6I_3)^{2012})}=(\det{(6I_3)})^{2012}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the Cayely Hamilton theorem the characteristic polynomial annihilates the matrix so

$$ (A^{3}-4A^{2}+A)^{2012}=(6I)^{2012}=6^{2012}I$$
and we have
$$\det(kI_n)=k^n$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the $det(kI_{n})=^{n}$ part

Comment: In your case $n=3$ and $I_3$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

Comment: THe determinant of the identity times some scalar is just product of the diagonals, which are all the same scalar, so since it is a $3\times{3}$, your determinant of $6I_3=6^3$.  This is true in the general case as mentioned above by @SamiBenRomdhane